# Adjust last columns on a table to fit content, but not the first one

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a draggable/resizable widget with a HTML table inside. This table contains 2 (maybe 3) columns. The first one is a client name list. The second one is a client type list. The third one (optional) is a group initials list. The font size of the information is configurable too, so it can be bigger or smaller.

I want to show (the best way possible) some informations on this table. I'm trying several configurations. The last one is as follow:

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}

table td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And the short HTML code is:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:70%">1. DEPUTADA CRISTINA SILVESTRI</td>
      <td stype="width:20%">Não Informou</td>
      <td style="width:10%">PPS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:70%">2. DEPUTADO ANDRE BUENO</td>
      <td stype="width:20%">Contra</td>
      <td style="width:10%">PDT</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I try like above, the first column gets a blank space in the end, and the second and third columns cut the information (with ellipsis) (see first image called wrong.png). I want the result like the second image (called ok.png). But if I have a big name (first column) I want it to cut like 70% with an ellipsis, so the last 2 columns can be displayed (see last image, called ok2.png). Finally, if I have a small table, I want all information to be displayed with an ellisis, not just the first column. How can I do that?

The images:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/fAD68]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412246/1959257) (rmehlinger answer)

Answer (score -1):

IMOE, when i have complicated table scenarios, I put  tags inside every cell. Take the advantage than divs can be CLASSsified to almost every need:

```
  <tr><td class='column_a'><div>...</div></td><td class='column_b'><div>...</div></td></tr>
```

HIH,

Answer (score -1):

you need to set max width

```css
td
{
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. DEPUTADA CRISTINA SILVESTRI</td>
      <td>Não Informou</td>
      <td>PPS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. DEPUTADO ANDRE BUENO</td>
      <td>Contra</td>
      <td>PDT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. It should be fill blank spaces to optimize it. See image result on https://imgur.com/a/mqjcb